# Compare to newline windows C++

Tags: c++, compare, newline

I have this simple code:

```
string isNewline(string text)
{   
    string toReturn;
    text == "\r\n" ? toReturn = "(newline)" : toReturn = text;
    return toReturn;
}
```

this function never returns a "(newline)" string, so I'm guessing that my comparison with newline character is wrong. How can I correct this?

PS. Windows function

Comment: You would have to show how it was being called.

Comment: What about a trim before comparison? 
`remove(text.begin(), text.end(), ' '); // #include <algorithm>`

Comment: `text == "\r\n" ? toReturn = "(newline)" : toReturn = text;` is valid but weird. Prefer `toReturn = (text == "\r\n" ? "(newline)" : text);` (and you might as well just `return` immediately!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your `isNewline` function.

**The problem is how you get the string to be passed to `isNewline` function.**

I suspect you use something like `getline(fin,aLine)`  to get the string like below?

```
while(getline(fin,aLine)){
   cout<<aLine<<endl; //aLine will never contain newline character because getline never save it
   cout<<isNewline(aLine)<<endl; // so this will never output "(newline)"
}
```

`getline` does not save the newline character into `aLine`

Comment: Yeah... My problem was here. This answer helped me understanding it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


string isNewline(string text)
{   
    string toReturn;
    text == "\r\n" ? toReturn = "(newline)" : toReturn = text;
    return toReturn;
}

int main() {
    cout << isNewline( "\r\n" ) << "\n";
    cout << isNewline( "zod" ) << "\n";
}
```

prints:

```
(newline)
zod
```

Note that you really want to be passing the string as a `const::string &`

Answer (score 0):

Is not a good ideia to use assignment inside a conditional operator.
But, there are anothers way to do the same thing. Look..

Use this:

```
string isNewline(string text)
{
    return (text == "\r\n" ? "(newline)" : text);
}
```

or

```
string isNewline(string text)
{
    string toReturn;
    toReturn = text == "\r\n" ? "(newline)" : text;
    return toReturn
}
```

I hope help you!

Comment: That line will return the result of ternary operator, that would be, ("newline") ou text, and both are string types!

Comment: So, what is the difference between these functions and the one OP posted? They are all the same, written in different ways.

Comment: @Jonatas: [Yes you can](http://www.ideone.com/9ScTQ). An assignment is a valid expression; consider `if (a = 2) {..}`. _However_, your alternative suggestions are superior in terms of code style.

Comment: It's the conditional operator. And yes you can.

Comment: @Neil: In the sense of wider terminology, it is a ternary operator called the "conditional operator".

Comment: Thanks man..
I know that a assignment is a valid expression, but the return of a assignmente would be (true | false).. Cause that its not a good idea put inside a ternary operator.. Cause almost always will return true.
BTW, I know a lot about C but not so much about C++.. Probably you are right and i am wrong..