# Reading files with the same extension in a directory and count their lines

Tags: c, eof, eol

I am having this problem with my code. I've been trying to open files that have the same extension and read the number of lines in the file that is in the directory. 
So, here is what I've done:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
int countLines(char name[]);
int main()
{
    struct dirent *de;
    DIR *dr=opendir(".");
    char check[16]=".nkt";
    int i;
    char name[64];
    int count=0;

    if(dr==NULL)
    {
        printf("Didn't open!");
        return 0;
    }

    while((de=readdir(dr))!=NULL)
    {
        if((strstr(de->d_name, check))!=NULL)
        {
            strcpy(name, de->d_name);
            countLines(name);
        }
    }

    closedir(dr);

    return 0;
}

int countLines(char name[])
{
    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen(name,"r");
    char ch;
    int lines=0;
    while(!feof(fp))
    {
        ch=fgetc(fp);
        if(ch=='\n')
        {
            lines++;
        }
    }

    fclose(fp);

    printf("%d\n", lines);
}
```

and the result that I am getting is always like :

```
2
2
2
```

Even though every file has 54 lines.
**Would gladly appreciate some help.**
PS. The extension is .nkt

Comment: This code works fine for me. Which Operating system are you using?

Comment: Try \r instead of \n

Comment: @RoyaGhasemzadeh I am using Windows 10 Pro

Comment: @RoyaGhasemzadeh now it prints out 0's

Comment: Have a look at this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6162731/compare-to-newline-windows-c
It might be helpful. I dont have access to your files so i can't be sure.

Comment: In windows The new line is "\r\n" so you can't match it with one character. so '\n' will not work.

Comment: @RoyaGhasemzadeh do you suggest I do a string comparison or maybe if(c=='\r' || c=='\n')?

Comment: No if(c=='\r' || c=='\n') will not work. you will have to read a string and compare it. but because you only need to count the lines check my answer. I suggest you use getline.

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5431941/694576

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `countLines()` function you show  is stepping into several traps.

1. [`fgetc()`](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.7.1) returns `int` not `char` by intention. It does this to be able to return the End-of-File state, aside all other possible character values. A simple `char` cannot do this.
2. The use of `feof()` to identify the End-of-File fails as the EOF indicator is set only after the last read hitting the end of the file has been completed. So a loop steered using `feof()` typically iterated one time to often.

   A detailed discussion on this is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5431941/694576).
3. A text file's last line not necessarily carries an End-of-File indicator, but you mostly likely still want count that line. Special logic needs to be applied to cover this case.

A possible implementation of a function taking care off all those issue mentioned above might look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* Returns the number of lines inside the file named file_name 
   or -1 on error. */
long count_lines(const char * file_name)
{
  long lines = 0;
  FILE * fp = fopen(file_name, "r"); /* Open file to read in text mode. */
  if (NULL == fp)
  {
    lines = -1;
  }
  else
  {
    int previous = EOF;

    for (int current; (EOF != (current = fgetc(fp)));)
    {
      if ('\n' == current)
      {
        ++lines;
      }

      previous = current;
    }

    if (ferror(fp)) /* fgetc() returns EOF as well if an error occurred.
                       This call identifies that case. */
    {
      lines = -1;
    }
    else if (EOF != previous && '\n' != previous)
    {
      ++lines; /* Last line missed trailing new-line! */
    }

    fclose(fp);
  }

  return lines;
}
```

Regarding the discussion about different End-of-Line indicators inside the question's comment section:

The End-of-Line indicator for text files is implemented differently on different platforms (UNIX: `'\n'` vs. Windows: `\r\n` vs. ... (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline)).

To manoeuvre around this the C library function [`fopen()`](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.5.3) by default opens a file in so called "text-mode". If opened this way the C implementation takes care that each line's end is returned as a single `'\n'` character, the so called "new-line" character. Please note (as mentioned above under 3.) that for the last line there might be no End-of-Line indicator at all.